# How to create javascript POST request to server with Headers and Data

Tags: javascript, post, http-headers

I use JS automation framework for testing iOS application. In the middle of a test I need to create POST request to server to some money to user and then verify that changes are reflected in UI.

Request looks like: wwww.testserver.com/userAddMoney?user_id=1&amount=999

but to authorize on server I need to pass special parameters to Header of request:

**Headers:** X-Testing-Auth-Secret: kI7wGju76kjhJHGklk76

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See here on how to make an ajax call with Jquery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ See the header section on how to set header on the request. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

So basically you want to set the header of a POST request. You can do it only if its an ajax request (You can't set headers for a normal html form submission request). Here is a way to set headers for an ajax request:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange= function () {
    if (request.readyState==4) {
        //handle response
    }
}
request.open("POST", "url", true);
request.setRequestHeader("header", "blah blah");
request.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/plain");
request.send("post data");
```

Comment: I've pasted my data into your code. Unfortunately formatting is broken. I've uploaded code to pastebin [link]http://pastebin.com/bYvkGS8y  Please help me with two questions. Thanks in advance!