# POST JSON Object with multiple headers in php

Tags: php, json, laravel

Request header

```
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer [access token] 
Accept: application/json
```

if send unicode string with message, please set Content-Type charset to UTF-8

Following is a sample request of send service.

URL-https://example.com/requests

Method - POST

Body

```
{
    "outboundSMSMessageRequest": {
        "address": [
            "tel:+94771234567"
        ],
        "senderAddress": "tel:12345678",
        "outboundSMSTextMessage": {
            "message": "Test Message"
        },
        "clientCorrelator": "123456",
        "receiptRequest": {
            "notifyURL": "http://128.199.174.220:1080/sms/report",
            "callbackData": "some-data-useful-to-the-requester"
        },
        "senderName": "ACME Inc."
    }
}
```

How to post and get responce

Comment: Just `Content-Type: application/json` is enough.

Comment: how to set header and body

Answer (score 0):

ajax

```
headers: {
    'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
```

or vanilla js

[How to create javascript POST request to server with Headers and Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489481/how-to-create-javascript-post-request-to-server-with-headers-and-data)